# Securing vserver for CI

Tags: git, security, jenkins, server

so I started working in a small startup and we need a server for the software development. (Jenkins as CI, Bitbucket for git, Jira+Confluence)

Unfortuanalty we cannot use a own dedicated Server, so we thought about renting a virtual server somewhere.

**My question is**: Should we take further actions to improve the security (as ideally it should be in the local network) or is it fine to rely on the provided security features in the various services?

Comment: I'd recommend using TeamCity for CI instead of Jenkins. It is way better. ;-)

Comment: This question is too broad. What service are you considering? What are you trying to protect from? As a startup, you have limited resources -- where do you want to spend your time/energy? We can't answer those questions for you.